# Why .html() and .text() selects only the first word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code of jquery that gets the first word of the label.

```
var val = $(this).find('label').html(); // The value must be Graphic Designer
$(this).find('label').replaceWith('<input type=text value='+val+'); // The input's value is Graphic
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhd_reza/mSDRG)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the html close tag character `>` and it's string ender `'`, and you should add `"` in your input. Should be:

```
'<input type=text size=40 value="'+val+'" />'
                                ^       ^
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vgNS8/

Comment: also `type="text"` and `size="40"`.

Comment: OMG, I really should have thought of it before asking! Thank you Sergio!

Answer (score 7):

Build the input with jQuery instead:

```
$("#editInfoBtn").click(function(){
    $(".inline-update").each(function(){
        var val = $(this).find('label').html(),
                    // build the element here
                    $input = $('<input>',{attr:{'type':'text','size':40},val:val});
                // insert it here
        $(this).find('label').replaceWith($input);
    });
});
```

Chances are you're running into problem with the quotes.